# jQuery JSON looping through nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I currently have this:

```
    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('body');
    });
```

test.json looks like this:

`{"key1":{"key11":"value11","key12":"value12"},"key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}`

I'm getting:

```
[object Object]
value2
value3
```

How can I change it so it will loop through all the nested items regardless of how many nested values I have?

So for the above example I will get

```
value1
    value11
    value12
value2
value3
```

Comment: Why do you expect `value1` to be displayed?

Comment: @pimvdb not expecting it, my question is how do I make it display as a nested <ul>? also, is it possible to alter the code in a way that will automatically add nested <ul>'s according to the nesting in the JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a recursive loop function, but you'd have a problem: when a property is an object, there is no text to display because there is no string. So, you'll end up with:

```
- - value11
  - value12
- value2
- value3
```

because while `value2` is the string to display for item #2, it is an object that's displayed for item #1.

Anyway, this is what I made up: http://jsfiddle.net/uXww2/.

```
// obj is the object to loop, ul is the ul to append lis to
function loop(obj, ul) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if(val && typeof val === "object") { // object, call recursively
            var ul2 = $("<ul>").appendTo(
                $("<li>").appendTo(ul)
            );

            loop(val, ul2);
        } else {
            $("<li>", {
                id: key
            }).text(val).appendTo(ul);
        }
    });
}

$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  var ul = $("<ul>");

  loop(data, ul);

  ul.addClass("my-new-list").appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use the key as the top <li> content in case there are nested values?

Comment: @Or W: You'd have to give the li inside ul2 some text (the key variable).

Comment: this does not take arrays into account, you probably should write `$.isPlainObject(val) || $.isArray(val)`

Comment: using `typeof` is not recommended, since `typeof null === "object"` yields true

Comment: @Christoph: True. The OP only deals with strings, though (no arrays/`null`/etc), but I'll edit.

Comment: Almost 3 years since this was posted and still useful now. Thank you for helping me solve the issue I have had for the last few days.

Comment: how would you do this without the use of recursive calls ?

Answer (score 2):

so, what you want is a treeview looping through a json object

you can use this code i made myself recursively, test it ;)

```
var treestring      = "";
var myid            = "arv";
var json_object     = {your json}; 

var Tree = function (data) {
   this.data = data;
};

//1st step
Tree.renderTree(json_object, myid);

//2st step , this is a function
Tree.renderTree= function (json_object, myid) {
    $.each(json_object, function (key, val) {
        var m = new Tree(val);
        m.render(myid);
    });       
}

//3st step, this a function too
Tree.prototype.render = function (myid) {
    treestring = "<li class='category'> " + this.data.Name;
    //Check if has another arrays inside the current
    if (this.data.SubFolders) {
        treestring += "<ul id=" + this.data.ID + "</ul>";
        $("#" + myid).append(treestring);
        myid = this.data.ID;
        Tree.renderTree(this.data.Sub_Fodlers, myid);
    }
    else {
        treestring += "</li>";
        $("#" + myid).append(treestring);
    }
};


//HTML
<div id="tree"> 
     <ul id="arv"></ul>
</div>
```

//this.data.{something} ate the fields defined in your json object

enjoy ;)