# jQuery JSON looping through nested objects to create menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON string that I'm getting through with $.getJSON:

```
{
    "Menu1":"Item1",
    "Menu2": {
        "SubMenu1":"SubItem1",
        "SubMenu2":"SubItem2"
    },
    "Menu3":"Item3",
    "Menu4": {
        "SubMenu2": {
            "SubSubMenu1":"SubSubItem1"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I loop through to represent a menu such as:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Menu2
        <ul>
            <li>SubItem1</li>
            <li>SubItem2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Menu4
        <ul>
            <li>SubMenu2
                <ul>
                    <li>SubSubItem1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the trouble with your accepted answer to your other question: [jQuery JSON looping through nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553539/jquery-json-looping-through-nested-objects)?

Comment: @RightSaidFred The other answer solves only a part of my question.. I'm trying to get the Key in the <li> in case it's a nested object

Comment: Did you try on your own? All you need is to change this `$("<li>").appendTo(ul)` to this `$("<li>").append(key).appendTo(ul)`. http://jsfiddle.net/uXww2/1/

Comment: You're welcome. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/uXww2/2/) using your new data.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick;

```
function buildNode(key, val) {
  var html="";
  if(typeof val === 'string') {
    html+= '<li>'+val+'</li>';
  }
  else { //assumtion: if it isn't a string it's an object
    html+= '<li>'+key +'<ul>';
    for(var subkey in val) {
      html+= buildNode(subkey, val[subkey]);
    }
    html+= '</ul></li>';
  }
  return html;
}

//assumtion: url serves the json string in question
$.getJSON(url,function(data) {

var html = '<ul>';
for(var key in data) {
  html+= buildNode(key, data[key]);
}
html+='</ul>';

//the variable html now  hold the html you are looking for
});
```

Note: this could be done more "correctly" by using `hasOwnProperty` in the loops and do stricter type checking etc. but i will leave that up to the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/XE6Nw/

```
function makeMenu(data) {
    var html = "<ul>";
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        html += "<li>";
        if (typeof val === "object")
           html +=  key + makeMenu(val);
        else
           html += val;
        html += "</li>";
    });
    html += "</ul>";
    return html;
};

$(makeMenu(data)).appendTo("body");
```

Insert the above into your `$.getJSON()` success callback as appropriate. And, obviously, append to the appropriate element - I've just appended to the body for ease of testing in the jsfiddle above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use jQuery to achieve this. What I'd do is a function and use some recursion (you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsvidor/GvR7x/):

```
function createMenu(items) {
    var menu = document.createElement('ul'),
        i, item;

    for (i in items) {
        if (i != '__proto__' && items[i]) {
            item = document.createElement('li');

            if (typeof(items[i]) === 'object') {
                item.textContent = i;
                item.appendChild(createMenu(items[i]));
            } else {
                item.textContent = items[i];
            }

            menu.appendChild(item);
        }
    }

    return menu;
}
```

And then you could use jQuery to append to an HTML element.

```
var menu = { 
    Menu1: 'Item1',
    Menu2: {
        SubMenu1: 'SubItem1',
        SubMenu2: 'SubItem2'
    },
    Menu3: 'Item3',
    Menu4: {
        SubMenu2: {
            SubSubMenu1: 'SubSubItem1'
        }
    }
};

$('#someElement').html(createMenu(menu));
```