# Knockout mapping for nested json

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I was trying to create a json schema viewer and editor. I need to show the dynamically generated nested json as nested table and must be able to edit them or add new. for that I was trying to map a nested json to knockout observable and to show them as a nested table

[JSBin sample](http://jsbin.com/ogutip/2/edit)

But I failed to map it can anyone help me map it correctly and help me arrange the child tables as next 'tr'.

I'm not getting any error but the values are not displayed.

Comment: The answer by 'amakhrov' is correct but can anyone update the answer for the result I need: ' Is there any way to bring the expanded as a new row? so that it won't extend to the left bt will be show one below another '

Comment: Why is there a downvote and a vote to close this question? Care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is absolutely not clean, but it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezg5U/

Basically, I track the path within the json data and dynamically set KO bindings like

```
data-bind="'text: values()[0]._values()[1].key'"
```

Also the textarea elements have the "value: " binding, thus storing the updated data in the view model.

The DIV below the table is updated automatically and shows the value of the nested key: vm.values()[0]._values()[0].key() - so you can see that the model is actually updated when a user changes the value.

Comment: Thanks man. Is there any way to bring the expanded as a new row? so that it won't extend to the left bt will be show one below another

Comment: The data that I use is dynamically generated so when data is different this code is falling apart :(

Comment: Its a 3 level data. The data can go upto 'n' levels

Comment: The issue is not about the number of levels. It's because the keys in this json are not valid JS variable names.

I updated the code to account for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezg5U/1/

Comment: Yeah thanks I saw that too. But still I'm not able to save it. If I edit the value for 'Allowances&DAId' in one place its changing in other row also.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to pass the array index in one place :). Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/ezg5U/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34824/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-amakhrov)