# how to print all values of a nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a nested object like that:

```
var conversation = {
    'John': {
        1: 'Test message 1',
        2: 'Test message 2',
        'Reply': {
            3: 'Test message 3',
            4: 'Test message 4'
        }
    },
    'Jack': {
        5: 'Test message 5',
        6: 'Test message 6'
    }
};
```

I need to get all final values, so for that example, it is:

```
Test message 1
Test message 2
Test message 3
Test message 4
Test message 5
Test message 6
```

How to iterate over the object? Is there any built-in function in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically display JSON file contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478005/dynamically-display-json-file-contents)

Comment: You could use You could use You could use recursion recursion recursion.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use some recursion to check to see if the key being iterated over is an object or not, then print:

```
function printValues(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            printValues(obj[key]);   
        } else {
            console.log(obj[key]);    
        }
    }
}

printValues(conversation);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c7th1t8r/

Comment: If you just want to print, wouldn't you just use `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: @JuanMendes -- Why would you use that to print? That'll stringify the object...I think OP wants the values of each key.

Comment: if you want to make it shorter replace `if` and `else` statments with: `(obj[key].constructor === Object) ? printValues(obj[key]) : console.log(obj[key]);` I changed it to `.constructor === Object` because `typeof []` is also returns `object`

Comment: I would add a first condition checking if the object has the specified property: `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){`

Comment: @JuanMendes: `JSON.stringify()` returns keys also, but I need only the values.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has the [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function which you could use, in addition to a bit of a recursion to plumb down into your object until you reach something you can print.

```js
var conversation = {
  'John': {
    1: 'Test message 1',
    2: 'Test message 2',
    'Reply': {
      3: 'Test message 3',
      4: 'Test message 4'
    }
  },
  'Jack': {
    5: 'Test message 5',
    6: 'Test message 6'
  }
};

function iterate(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'string') {
    $('#log').append((obj + '<br/>'));
  }
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
      iterate(value);
    });
  }
}

iterate(conversation);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that and fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for jQuery solution. I think it is the jQuery version of tymeJV answer.

Answer (score 3):

A more functional way :

```js
const getObjectValues = (obj) => (obj && typeof obj === 'object')
 ? Object.values(obj).map(getObjectValues).flat()
 : [obj]
```

This returns an array that can then be printed :

```js
console.log(getObjectValues(conversation))
// ["Test message 1", "Test message 2", "Test message 3", "Test message 4", "Test message 5", "Test message 6"]
```

EDIT:

If `Array.flat` is not available in your context, it can be written this way :

```js
const getObjValues = (obj) => (obj && typeof obj === 'object')
  ? Object
    .values(obj)
    .map(getObjValues)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
  : [obj]
```

Comment: Careful - typeof(null) will return "object" due to a weird JS bug dating way back.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the answer by [@tymejv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686485/tymejv) to return the count and add keys to an array in case you don't want to print them. (You can also remove the array if you just want the count)

```
calculateNestedPropertyCount = (object, propertyCount = 0, properties = []) => {
    for (const key in object) {
        if (typeof object[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(object[key])) {
            calculateNestedPropertyCount(object[key], propertyCount, properties);
        }
        propertyCount++;
        properties.push(key);
    }
    return properties;
}
```